# Schedule jobs in database with nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, scheduler, jobs

I have a web application, where users can schedule different jobs. 
I'am not sure how to proceed with this.
All the nodejs schedulers out there basically reads the schedule from within the code. I can of course implement this cron like schedule to be read from a database, but I'am not sure if its the most effective way?

If I back the solution with a database I would need to query that database, let say each second, to see if there is any schduled jobs that needs to be handled. I can't read them once a day, because new jobs might be added on a regular basis.
Keeping them in memory dosen't seem very efficient either?

Am I looking for a different kind of technology to handle this, than a scheduler+database?

We are talkning around 10.000 jobs for the time being (as a maximum). They are mostly related to sending emails and/or giving notifications within the application itself.

Comment: How did you go with this? Did you end up finding something?